# Can the aside tag be first in an article?

Tags: html, w3c-validation, semantic-markup

Can the `aside` tag be first in an `article` tag?

I been speed reading the specification for `aside` tag but couldn´t really find anything that will explain it to me.

Any HTML5 experts that can explain if this is a legit structure?

```
<article>
 <aside>
   <h2>Aside Heading</h2>
   <p>
     Aside info
   </p>
 </aside>
 <h2>Article Heading</h2>
 <p>
   Article info
 </p>
</article>
```

Or is it important that `aside` is after the `article` content like this:

```
 <article>
 <h2>Article Heading</h2>
 <p>
   Article info
 </p>
 <aside>
   <h2>Aside Heading</h2>
   <p>
     Aside info
   </p>
 </aside>
</article>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second snippet is a better choice—it’s better for the `aside` to not precede the article heading.

The reason is that while `aside` as the first child of an `article` is not invalid, look at [the results of trying it in the HTML checker (validator)](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%2C%3C%2521DOCTYPE%2520html%3E%250D%250A%3Chtml%3E%250D%250A%3Chead%3E%250D%250A%3Ctitle%3ETest%3C%252Ftitle%3E%250D%250A%3Carticle%3E%250D%250A%2520%3Caside%3E%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%3Ch2%3EAside%2520Heading%3C%252Fh2%3E%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%3Cp%3E%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520Aside%2520info%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%3C%252Fp%3E%250D%250A%2520%3C%252Faside%3E%250D%250A%2520%3Ch2%3EArticle%2520Heading%3C%252Fh2%3E%250D%250A%2520%3Cp%3E%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520Article%2520info%250D%250A%2520%3C%252Fp%3E%250D%250A%3C%252Farticle%3E#textarea) and you’ll see it causes this warning:

> Warning: Article lacks heading. Consider using h2-h6 elements to add identifying headings to all articles.

That warning’s not an HTML checker bug. Other implementations of [the HTML outline algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#outlines) such as https://h5o.github.io/ will also see that article as lacking a heading.

Obviously there is a heading there—`<h2>Article Heading</h2>`—but due to the requirements of the HTML outline algorithm (which can seem odd…), if that `aside` element precedes the heading for the `article`, that causes the outline algorithm to consider the `article` as lacking a heading.

So, one choice for marking up your content in a way that the outline algorithm would be happier with and that would avoid the warning from the HTML checker is this:

```html
<article>
 <h2>Article Heading</h2>
 <aside>
   <h2>Aside Heading</h2>
   <p>
     Aside info
   </p>
 </aside>
 <p>
   Article info
 </p>
</article>
```

That is, just move the `<h2>Article Heading</h2>` before the `aside` but keep all else the same.

Another way is to do what you’ve done in your example in the question: move the `aside` to the end of the `article`. If you look at [the results of trying that second example from the question in the HTML checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%2C%3C%2521DOCTYPE%2520html%3E%250D%250A%3Chtml%3E%250D%250A%3Chead%3E%250D%250A%3Ctitle%3ETest%3C%252Ftitle%3E%250D%250A%2520%3Carticle%3E%250D%250A%2520%3Ch2%3EArticle%2520Heading%3C%252Fh2%3E%250D%250A%2520%3Cp%3E%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520Article%2520info%250D%250A%2520%3C%252Fp%3E%250D%250A%2520%3Caside%3E%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%3Ch2%3EAside%2520Heading%3C%252Fh2%3E%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%3Cp%3E%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520Aside%2520info%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%3C%252Fp%3E%250D%250A%2520%3C%252Faside%3E%250D%250A%3C%252Farticle%3E#textarea), you’ll see it causes no warnings and no errors.